# Python Datatable: Set Data Type by column

Tags: python, datatable, format

I'm a begineer with Python.
I've a dataframes where some columns contain strings, some int and some floats.
I need to set just some columns to visualize floats as int.
In this case I need to perform this action where the header value is FX, FY, FZ.

I also want to keep just 1 digit after the comma for columns DX, DY,DZ.

[Screeshot of the table I want to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4pQa.png)

I'm using this code

```html
class TestApp(Frame):
        """Basic test frame for the table"""
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            self.parent = parent
            Frame.__init__(self)
            self.main = self.master
            self.main.geometry('600x400+200+100')
            #self.main.title('Table app')
            frame2 = Frame(self.main)
            frame2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
            #df1 = TableModel.getSampleData()
            self.table = pt1 = Table(frame2, dataframe=df1, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)
            pt1.show()
            pt1.rowheader.bgcolor = 'orange'
            pt1.setRowColors(rows=2, clr='red', cols='all')
            pt1.setRowColors(rows=[3, 4], clr='green', cols=[0, 1])
            pt1.setRowColors(rows=[5], clr='blue', cols=[-3, -1])
            pt1.cellbackgr = 'grey'

            #set some options
            options = {'colheadercolor':'green','floatprecision': 1, 'fontsize':9, 'rowheight':18}
            config.apply_options(options, pt1)
            
            pt1.show()
            return
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out that all these solutions create an integer by truncating the float number.
So for if I transform 5.9 in integer, I get 5 and not 6.
I've found a workaround. For example for column 'FX' and 'FY':

```
df1['FX'] = df1['FX'].round(decimals = 0)
df1['FY'] = df1['FY'].round(decimals = 0)
df1.FX = df1.FX.apply(np.int64)
df1.FY = df1.FY.apply(np.int64)
```

This solution works, but it's not elegant.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'first_column':  [1.2,5.6,7.8],
        'second_column': [3.376,4.34654,8.6373]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

before:

```py
print (df)
```

```
   first_column  second_column
0           1.2        3.37600
1           5.6        4.34654
2           7.8        8.63730
```

after:

```py
df.second_column = df.second_column.apply(np.int64)
print (df)
```

```
   first_column  second_column
0           1.2              3
1           5.6              4
2           7.8              8
```

Comment: you're welcome. if you need anything, connect with me at yishai rasowsky at gmail.